# CSS: margin-right: auto acting weird

Tags: html, css, margin

HTML:

```
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Categories 1</a>
                <ul id="cat1">
                    <li class="first"><a href="#">temp1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">temp2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">temp3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
  background-color: #0000FF;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 15px 0 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  font: 12px Tahoma;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px #000;
  text-align: center;
} 

#menu > li{
  display: inline;
}
li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.first{
  margin-top: 12px;
}

#cat1 > li{
  display: block;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#cat1 > li > a{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px #000;
```

}

When i use `margin-left: auto` in `#cat > li` it is woring properly. `margin-right:auto` on the other hand doesn't get the full margin, and I don't understand why this is.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfN7t/25/

Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mayb you should set `<li>` inline-block , maybe text-align:center and reset margin/padding of `<ul>` second level too :)

http://jsfiddle.net/ZfN7t/26/

```
ul {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}
#menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: That was it, thank you! But why inline-block instead of just inline? I'm just having problems understanding why my code didn't work. margin-left auto worked properly, but not the right.

Comment: inline-block turns li to be a box that exist and be sized. it has consistent layout, where inline is just translucide.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the default padding for html elements and it should work like expected.

```
ul,li
{
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/sNYru/1/)**